# Efficiently define new columns on data.table with conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have large data.table with 6 million rows.

Sample data is:

DT:

```
VAR1 VAR2 VAR3.....
6           5
NA    5     1
"?"   2     0
```

I like to redefine two columns.
I used the code below and it works very slow.

```
DT=DT[,':='(VAR1=ifelse(DT$VAR1 == "?" | is.na(DT$VAR1) |  is.null(DT$VAR1) | 
                  length(DT$VAR1) == 0 ,  1 , DT$VAR1),
            VAR2 = ifelse ( DT$VAR2 == "?" | is.na(DT$VAR2) |  
                  is.null(DT$VAR2) | length(DT$VAR2) == 0, "" , DT$VAR2)) ,with=FALSE]
```

Is there a way I can modify the code so it work faster?

Comment: Why do you do `DT=DT`? When you use `':='`, `DT` is being updated by referenceץ

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `DT$VAR1` within the scope of a `data.table` object. Just do `ifelse(VAR1 == "?" | is.na(VAR1) | etc....`

Comment: I tried what David Arenburg suggest, but i get an error

Comment: @AlonHazan, what have you tried?, please share the code

Comment: @AlonHazan, try `DT[, ':='(VAR1= ifelse(grepl("\\d", VAR1), VAR1, 1), VAR2 = ifelse(grepl("\\d", VAR2), VAR2, ""))]`

Comment: Or better see my answer on how to avoid `ifelse`

Comment: I recieve the error: LHS of := must be a single column name when with=TRUE. When with=FALSE the LHS may be a vector of column names or positions.
>

Comment: I'm not sure why are you getting this error. Did you try the code in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you trying to do, but you have several fundamental mistakes here regarding how to operate with a `data.table` object:

1. No need in doing `DT=DT` as `:=` updates `DT` by reference
2. No need in referencing to `DT` within the scope of a `data.table` object by doing `DT$VAR1`, just do `VAR1` instead
3. `ifelse` is very inefficient and slow (despite being vectorized) so always try to avoid it (especially imbedded `ifelse`). In your case, I'm suspecting that you are trying to replace everything that is not a number with `1` in `VAR1` and with `""` in `VAR2`, correct? If so, you could only look for the numeric values instead, and hence, avoid the `ifelse` statement

Try

```
DT[!grepl("\\d", VAR1), VAR1 := "1"]
DT[!grepl("\\d", VAR2), VAR2 := ""]
```

Which will return (for your example data set)

```
DT
#    VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
# 1:    6         5
# 2:    1    5    1
# 3:    1    2    0
```

Comment: OP could still use your (better) approach but still use their conditions if they so desired.  ie `DT[VAR1=="?"|is.na(VAR1)|is.null(VAR1)|length(VAR1)==1, VAR1:=1]` just incase `grepl` doesn't meet their exact needs